# can't access mysql in zend server

Tags: mysql, zend-framework, mysql.sock

```
Abhimanyus-MacBook-Pro:~ abhimanyuaryan$ /usr/local/zend/mysql/bin/mysql -u root

ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through 

socket '/usr/local/zend/mysql/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
```

I was trying to use MySQL database via terminal using the above command but then this error message showed up. How to fix it?

Comment: looks like mysql.sock access is not permitted, try `-h127.0.0.1`

Answer (score 0):

try bellow command

**mysql -u root -h localhost -p**

and give the root password
or you can install phpmyadmin and use it directly form the **http://localhost/phpmyadmin** after installing phpmyadmin.